# How to read form data using OCR and then convert the data read by OCR into structured data?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, ocr, text-extraction

I wish to read data from Physical forms filled in by customers (Address change form), use OCR to read this data.
Then be able to convert the data into a structured JSON data. Then I can feed this data to existing processes to perform actual task like - Address Update.

I understand that I need to create a model which will perform 2 things:
Model to perform OCR which will read handwritten texts from the physical forms.
Model to transform data ( raw OCR  text string ) into structured address change request in JSON format.

I have come across some libraries for OCR like pytesseract, but I am not getting any clue for second part.

How can I build this locally? How much time it will take me to complete this solution included time needed to train the model?

Answer (score 0):

try using pyTesseract and opencv

https://builtin.com/data-science/python-ocr

```
from pyTesseract import Output
import pyTesseract
import cv2

filename = 'image_01.png'
image = cv2.imread(filename)

results = pyTesseract.image_to_data(image, 
output_type=Output.DICT)
```